# How to change file names in a string using Regex c#

Tags: c#, xml, regex, string, replace

I uploaded a xml file to a string variable, correctly

my xml file is of the form

```
<Asset>01.xmf</Asset>
<Index>0</Index>
</Mesh>
</BodyPart0>
<BodyPart1>
<BodyPartId>1</BodyPartId>
<Material>
<TextureMap0>
<Asset>chkn_xrf_bd7580097080fe4f10fbf857ed5c27b8.xrf</Asset>
<Index>-1</Index>
</TextureMap0>
</Material>
<Mesh>
<Asset>02.xmf</Asset>
<Index>1</Index>
</Mesh>
</BodyPart1>
<BodyPart10>
<BodyPartId>10</BodyPartId>
<Material>
<TextureMap0>
<Asset>chkn_xrf_3b5aa82b4c3e67599e4091f0fcefa2a8.xrf</Asset>
<Index>-1</Index>
</TextureMap0>
</Material>
<Mesh>
<Asset>11.xmf</Asset>
```

I want to replace all the files extension. XMF already defined by another name.

For example **01.xmf** to **newNAME.xmf**

but when I run the following code, the result is not consistent, I think that is because the file name (**01.xmf**) **contain the special character "." (dot)**

```
stringINDEX string = GetXmlString (indexXML);/ / Load xml file in stringINDEX

string pattern = lbString1; / / lbString1 = "01.xmf" 
Rgx = new Regex Regex (pattern);

stringINDEX = rgx.Replace (stringINDEX, lbString2);/ / lbString2 = "newNAME.xmf"
```

how could solve it using regex?

Answer (score 2):

Just use String.Replace() instead of Regex.Replace()...

Comment: ..so many people are over-hyped by RegEx when this is such a simple find-replace..

Comment: I try the first time the common way.

stringINDEX = stringINDEX.Replace (lbString1, lbString2);

but as not working, which is the special character "." (dot) which brings problems.

but not how to do it with regex, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

. is a metacharacter in regex. That means you need to escape it, by putting a backslash before it, for regex to look for a literal . rather than the metacharacter . which means 'one of any character.'

So you want to do \. BUT WAIT - depending on what you're making the regex in, the backslash might be considered important and escaped before it even reaches the regex parsing engine. You might need \\. (so the \\ is turned into \ which with . is turned into . literal)

Read about all the metacharacters in regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

EDIT: To prove my point - I had to edit this post and double up all my backslashes so YOU would see the correct amount :)